# Cleaning space on samsung galaxy s8

Tags: samsung, storage, insufficient-memory, samsung-galaxy-s-8

I frequently receive message from s8 that details storage space is running out. Analyzing my storage space details this :

How can I receive more detail as to what apps are allocating space ? As detail below does not show what apps I should clean ?

[image]
<sup>(click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Starting point: Our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](/tags/insufficient-memory/info). Have you already consulted with it and its links?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the Google Play Store and that might show apps and what is taking the space or you can search on your phone for **My Files** and delete items that show to be too big.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to: Settings -> Apps -> Settings - > Sort by size